# Interruptible sleep in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sleep, interrupt

I'm in a worker thread and want to sleep for a specified period of time (usually a few hundreds milliseconds), but the sleep should be interruptible. Here is what I have come up with

```
void DummyScope::sleepForSamples() {
   if(m_sampleSleep < 100) {
      MySleeper::sleep(m_sampleSleep);
      return;
   }

   // sleep in periods of 100 ms, to be responsible for shutdown requests      
   qint64 t = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
   qint64 end = t + m_sampleSleep;

   while(t + 100 <= end) {
      MySleeper::sleep(100);
      t = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();

      // TODO: check here whether we are interrupted
   }

   if(end > t) {
      MySleeper::sleep(end - t);
   }
}
```

However that looks a bit convoluted and I wonder whether there's a better way to do this. Is using a `QWaitCondition` with a timeout-wait a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Is using a QWaitCondition with a timeout-wait a better solution?'

Yes!

The sleep() loop, apart from needlessly running every 100ms, has an average 'interrupt' latency of 50ms.

Comment: Can you give a rationale/some background please? Things like wait conditions and mutexes sound like heavy POSIX stuff. In contrast, in my loop there are only basic sleeps.

Comment: You don't need any mutex to just 'if QWaitCondition::wait(timeout)'.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think it is because with a timer, your process never wakes up, instead it is the OS scheduler that detects when your process needs to be interrupted. Also, this has a better latency, with your loop, there will be an average latency of your timeout/2 before you wake to process an event.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: do you mean heavy from a performance point of view or from a library/code point of view?

Comment: @MartinJames: http://library.maemodocs.nokia.com/fremantle/index.jsp?topic=/org.maemo.mica.maemosdk.help.api.cpp.qt46/html/qwaitcondition.html shows that you do need a mutex.

Comment: Only one thread is waiting, so why raise a mutex?  A mutex to safely check.. what?

Comment: @Marin according to the Qt 4.8 docs, there is no "wait" function that takes merely a timeout.

Comment: OK, use a QSemaphore instead with a 'tryAcquire(1,timeout )'.  The only thing I would then add is to ensure that the sema is empty at the time the wait starts with a 'tryAcquire(1)' loop, (just in case the thread was 'interrupted' more than once since it last waited).

Comment: @MartinJames: no offence, but we seem to have a different view on condition variables/semaphores: I believe you see condition variables for shooting signals and semaphores for anything more intelligent, I see condition variables as a way of passing changes in conditions and a semaphore to me is merely a condition variable with a counter...

Comment: I only suggested semaphores because @JohannesSchaub-litb commented that the Qt condvars lacked a simple wait() at V4.8.  Creating a mutex for the purpose of checking that the time period has, in fact, elapsed and that the one thread has not spuriously run seemed a bit OTT, after all, many OS do not support the 'spurious wakeup' feature.  Perhaps some developers should move to Windows to improve the reliability of their apps <g>

Comment: AFAIK, Qt conditions does not have that "spurious wakeup" thing?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - don't know.  If based on pthread condvars and linux, then quite possibly yes.

Comment: thanks. it turned out a wait condition is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Definitely wait on a condition variable and let the accompanying condition tell you why you were interrupted.
If you don't have to use QT-threads, c++11 and boost let you add a predicate to wait_for/timed_wait, so spurious wakeups don't mess with your timeout.

Of course, it is even more convienent if you can go 1 step further and don't bother with a timeout (if the condition variable can handle all cases).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I only just found out about the predicate passing in boost/c++11 (if that is the the spurious wakeup thing that you ask).  Qt (and other implementations I know of) don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait directly on the mutex with `QMutex::tryLock(int timeout)`, if you lock and unlock it from another thread.